# A quick way to copy a postgres database over the network

Tags: postgresql

I have been using this command to rapidly make clones of my database within the same server

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb WITH TEMPLATE originaldb OWNER dbuser;
```

What if I wanted to do this over our local network to a second server?  Is that possible?

I am on Postgresql 9.2 one Win 7 x64 (both machines).

Answer (score 3):

Use `pg_dump`:

```
pg_dump -h host1 -Fc originaldb | pg_restore -h host2 -d newdb
```

Ideally, you'd run this on either host1 or host2.

Comment: Excuse me my Windows ignorance but is a pipe operator available there?

Comment: I don't know about the native Windows shell, but it might be a good idea to install bash anyway if you want to do much with PostgreSQL command line tools.

Comment: It often speeds things up to add `--jobs=X` to pg_restore where X is the cpu count of the restore target host.

Comment: Parallel restore is unlikely to be useful in this case.  In the above example, the dump and the restore run in parallel.  If you want to use parallel restore, you'd have to wait for the dump to finish first.  So you would probably not save any time after all.

Comment: About parallelization and the -Fc argument, I suggest -Fd instead. From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html: 
_pg_dump can be used to backup an entire database, then pg_restore can be used to examine the archive and/or select which parts of the database are to be restored. The most flexible output file formats are the “custom” format (-Fc) and the “directory” format (-Fd). They allow for selection and reordering of all archived items, support parallel restoration, and are compressed by default. The “directory” format is the only format that supports parallel dumps._

Comment: You might want to add your user and file name when using the -Fd argument. Assuming you are on host 2 and want to backup db in host 1 to host 2: `pg_dump -h IP_HOST_1 -U USER_HOST_1 -f /PATH/TO/DIR_NAME -Fd DB_NAME | pg_restore -h IP_HOST_2  -d NAME_DB_BACKUP`. The DIR_NAME will be created on your current directory in HOST_2 assuming that is where you are executing the shell command line.